# Why does uninstalling takes a lot of time whereas shift+delete deletes everything in a matter of seconds?

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is uninstalling programs on Windows so slow?](https://superuser.com/questions/89705/why-is-uninstalling-programs-on-windows-so-slow)

What do the uninstallers do throughout the uninstalling process?

Comment: If life was only so simple. . .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is uninstalling programs on Windows so slow?](http://superuser.com/questions/89705/why-is-uninstalling-programs-on-windows-so-slow) also see [Why do Windows Installers (.msi files) take so much longer to uninstall than other installers?](http://superuser.com/questions/43740/why-do-windows-installers-msi-files-take-so-much-longer-to-uninstall-than-oth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They delete registry entries, etc. Besides, MSI also saves uninsstall data in case the uninstall fails or is cancelled.