# Prevent System Restore Point from being created during Install

Tags: windows, installation, system-restore, windows-installer, volume-shadow-copy

Whenever I install using .MSI, the system freezes right after starting the Volume Shadow Copy Service/etc, and creating a System Restore Point.

If possible, I'd rather not disable System Restore, as this deletes all previous restore points. I also don't want to kill the service/process, although I haven't tried this one yet to see if it even works.

How can I prevent a system restore point from being created while installing using a MSI launcher?

Comment: Temporarily Disable "Volume Shadow Copy" service in Windows Services.

Comment: @Moab Oh, right. :) But is there any way to make it do this automatically before every install, and then revert it back after the install?

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: @Gareth I thought MSI was exclusive to Windows, but if you're asking which OS version, it's Vista Home Premium SP2.

Comment: @muntoo Thanks, I was after which version of Windows you were on. You could take a look at my answer below but not sure how effective it will be in fixing VSS, especially as a lot of the issues seem to be on Windows 2003 and not Vista.

Comment: @muntoo, I don't know of anything "automatic', I suppose one could use a script to disable and then enable, would make it a bit easier but not automatic. You would need to edit your original question to ask for help scripting to disable-enable Volume Shadow Copy service.

Comment: @Moab I wasn't looking for scripts, but oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down through [this thread](http://www.2brightsparks.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=932), there's a number of things you could try for repairing the Volume Shadow Copy Service if you wanted to give that a go.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**: [Linking to similar content on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/594660/how-can-i-speed-up-msi-package-install-and-uninstall/594661#594661). Remember that this takes you to information intended for system administrators. As a super user / power user, the below summary might be better.

---

**UPDATE**: **Windows Installer 5** (available on Windows Server 2012, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7) now features a new property [**MSIFASTINSTALL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can be used to **speed up the installation of a large MSI package**. See the link above for valid values. I would suggest **3** for no restore point, and only FileCosting (the process of determining disk space requirement). Here is a sample:

> **msiexec.exe /I "D:\winzip112.msi" /QN MSIFASTINSTALL=3**

It is also possible to set the [**DISABLEROLLBACK**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to disable rollback support in the MSI installer. **I would strongly advise against using this unless you are staging a fresh PC.** This is a special case when you can just start over if something fails. For a computer in real use I would not recommend enabling this property.

The irony is that disabling rollback will speed up things the most if you are running a huge update package that replaces lots of files. It could be quite significant, but unsafe.

Comment: Reading the documentation i dont think this is related to System Restore, but about the rollback process which is required if an installation fails.

Comment: The MSIFASTINSTALLER relates to System Restore and file costing (which is the comparison of the size of the files to install versus the size of existing, installed files - among other things), DISABLEROLLBACK relates to the creation of backup files to restore the system in case the installation fails.